# Changing cell color if it equals values in a list conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors

I have two CF rules within the range F7:F446, one rule is: =ISNUMBER(MATCH($D7:$D446,required_refs!$A:$A,0)) to check if the cells in the D column are equal to any of the values listed in the A column of sheet "required_refs", if they are, it turns the F column cell red. The second rule is to check if the F column cell is empty or not =LEN($F$7:$F$446)>0 and formatted to change the fill to no color. The reason is, because once the F column cell is red, the user will click on the F column cell to eventually place a value in that cell. So, I want to the cell to return back to a no-fill if there is data in the cell. I have the CF rule that turns the cell red first and back to white after that rule. Currently, the f colored cells turn red but not back to white. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try/rearrange/edit to get these CF rules to work properly?
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have your rules in the wrong order.  If you open **Conditional formatting -> Manage rules**, you get the *Conditional Formatting Rules Manager*:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

When the rules are arranged as in the screenshot above (first ISNUMBER, then LEN), I get the effect you describe in your question.

If you reverse the order of the rules (use the arrow buttons on the header bar), then you will get the behaviour you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need the F column cell to turn red first, then check if the F column cell is blank. If it isn't blank, turn the F column cell back to a no-fill. When I switch the order of the CF rules, the F column cell never turns red, it just stays white all the time.

Comment: Interesting.  What version of Excel are you using?  I tried this in Excel 2010, and it seemed to work fine.  I will post another answer shortly with another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your rules into a single rule using multiplication (also use `ISBLANK()` as a less-cumbersome verision of `LEN(...) = 0`):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($D7:$D446,required_refs!$A:$A,0)) * ISBLANK($F$7:$F$446)
```

Excel treats the `TRUE` or `FALSE` results of these functions as integers, and multiplies them, so your formatting will only happen if the number matches the reference AND the cell in column F is blank.

Comment: @RobH Thanks.  What I *meant* and what I *wrote* didn't quite jive, there.  I've edited it to say what I meant.

Comment: Thanks so much for the adjustment. I deleted my previous two rules and replaced it with the one you suggested but the F colored cells do not turn red. When a value in the D column is one that requires the F column cell to turn red, it stays white. So, with that adjusted CF Rule, half of it is completed. I may go back to having two rules if I can't get the one rule to work. Any revisions/suggestions?

Comment: @anve I don't know what else to tell you.  Both of the solutions I've posted work for me when I test them using Excel 2010.  If you're using a different version, perhaps things work differently?  Is it possible that you're changing the CF only on a subset of fields, instead of the whole range?

Comment: The target ranges being referenced in these rules are only in the range of rows 7:446 and I'm using MS Excel 2016. I'll keep working with it, though. Thanks for your help!